# How could i fix an error (cs0120) in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity, I'm trying to make a press of a button increase the speed of the player. However, each time I run it. It gives me:

> Error  CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static
>   field, method, or property 'PlayerController.speed'

I've already tried changing order of the code, so what could I do?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upgrader1 : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        PlayerController PlayerController = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    }

    public void Upgrade1()
    {
        PlayerController.speed++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Upgrader1 : MonoBehaviour
{

PlayerController PlayerController; //It should be member variable

void Start()
{
    GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    PlayerController = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
}

public void Upgrade1()
{
    PlayerController.speed++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's always a good thing to use proper naming conventions.

```
    PlayerController _PlayerController; 
void Start() {

     GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player"); 
     _PlayerController = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();

  } 

  public void UpgradeSpeed() // I changed the name according to its functionality 
  {
     _PlayerController.speed++; 
  }
```

With this, you won't put PlayerController class reference again by mistake.